# Calculate not-null values' percentages of several columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a data frame as follows, how can I calculate `not-null values`' percentages of columns `A, C, D` in Pandas? Thank you.

```
   id     A      B     C     D
0   1   1.0    one   4.0   NaN
1   2   NaN    one  14.0   NaN
2   3   2.0    two   3.0 -12.0
3   4  55.0  three   NaN  12.0
4   5   6.0    two   8.0  12.0
5   6   NaN    two   7.0 -12.0
6   7 -17.0    one   NaN   NaN
7   8   NaN  three  11.0   NaN
```

The expected result is like this:

```
              id      A      B      C      D
0  not-nulls_pct  62.5%    NaN  75.0%  50.0%
1              1      1    one      4    NaN
2              2    NaN    one     14    NaN
3              3      2    two      3    -12
4              4     55  three    NaN     12
5              5      6    two      8     12
6              6    NaN    two      7    -12
7              7    -17    one    NaN    NaN
8              8    NaN  three     11    NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For count number of non NaNs values use [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) with [`DataFrame.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).

Then is necessary replace `100%` by missing values, one possible solution with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) - return `NaN`s by default, then create one row `DataFrame` with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose and prepend by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last set first value of `id` by custom value:

```
s = df.notna().mean()
df1 = s.mul(100).astype(str).add('%').mask(s == 1).to_frame().T
df = pd.concat([df1, df], ignore_index=True)

df.loc[0, 'id'] = 'not-nulls_pct'
print (df)
              id      A      B      C      D
0  not-nulls_pct  62.5%    NaN  75.0%  50.0%
1              1      1    one      4    NaN
2              2    NaN    one     14    NaN
3              3      2    two      3    -12
4              4     55  three    NaN     12
5              5      6    two      8     12
6              6    NaN    two      7    -12
7              7    -17    one    NaN    NaN
8              8    NaN  three     11    NaN
```

Or use [`setting with enlargement`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) with `loc`, then is necessary sorting index for first row in final `DataFrame`:

```
s = df.notna().mean()
df.loc[-1] = np.where(s != 1, s.mul(100).astype(str).add('%'), np.nan)
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
df.loc[0, 'id'] = 'not-nulls_pct'
print (df)
              id      A      B      C      D
0  not-nulls_pct  62.5%    NaN  75.0%  50.0%
1              1      1    one      4    NaN
2              2    NaN    one     14    NaN
3              3      2    two      3    -12
4              4     55  three    NaN     12
5              5      6    two      8     12
6              6    NaN    two      7    -12
7              7    -17    one    NaN    NaN
8              8    NaN  three     11    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please add some explanation?

Comment: why need `mean()`?

Comment: Because mean defitions is count of values divided by total count. It working nice, because Trues are processing like `1`.

Comment: I want to calculate selected columns `A, C, D`, but it doesn't matter. All is better. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc['per'] = ((df.count()/df.shape[0])*100).round(2).astype(str).add('%')
```

**output**

```
    id      A      B      C     D
0   1       1      one    4     NaN
1   2       NaN    one    14    NaN
2   3       2      two    3     -12
3   4       55     three  NaN   12
4   5       6      two    8     12
5   6       NaN    two    7     -12
6   7       -17    one    NaN   NaN
7   8       NaN    three  11    NaN
per 100.0%  62.5%  100.0% 75.0% 50.0%
```